# Non-final variable on a click listener

Tags: android, eclipse, textfield, onclicklistener

I am making an android application. I have a TextField and a button. Based on the value of the textfield, as soon as the user clicks the button I want to make something. I have the code:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String value = et.getText().toString();
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (value = "a" ) {
            //do something }
            }
        });
```

This however doesn't compile, saying "Cannot refer to a non-final variable value inside an inner class defined in a different method". Is there any way to fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: For comparison you have to use "==" not "=". For String comparison use String equals function.

Comment: well, you can't compare string with "=" operator. Basic java! I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
`final String value = et.getText().toString();`

and then use,
`if(value.equals("a") {
}`

Comment: Did it before answer and worked. Thanks and sorry for trouble

Comment: @user3265784 Well you should vote and select the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the value of a string you should use the "equals" method instead of "=".

The code will look like this:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final String value = et.getText().toString();
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (value.equals("a") ) {
           //do something }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String value = et.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Tried it ofc. It says Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean =/

Comment: try if(value.equals("a"))